# FFmpeg installation for x264 codec

Tags: ffmpeg, installation, x264

can anybody help me out in where can i find ffmpeg download for windows x264 codec , am developing a website which converts any file format to mp4h264 baseline format , everythng was fine with another wrap installer called MooO ffmpeg which i found in this link http://www.moo0.com/?top=http://www.moo0.com/software/FFmpeg/ 
evrythng is fine i can access the exe from my local system as the file is installed rather i could acess the same when its in remote as i knw the batch file location is different , any help related with ffmpeg x264 sourcecode or access batch file would be helpful.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You can download a build of ffmpeg with libx264 support for Windows at [Zeranoe FFmpeg Windows builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: I downloaded from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ - it does not have libx264/x264 support inbuilt. -- says: "Unknown decoder 'libx264'"

Answer (score 0):

found the problem , please guys download the 32 bit source file from the main hyperlink which is on the wrapped bundle of Zeranoe FFmpeg Windows builds., it works great.